# Database design/schema for position hierarchy approval process for leave management

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

How do I design a database so that when a lower employee (associate) requests a leave that needs to be approved by their superiors the request will find its way up to them?

- Any employee can request a leave.
- The approval of the request is limited to upper positions (superiors).
- Different departments have different depths in the position hierarchy.
- Every supervisor that is directly above the employee must approve the request. For example, a leave request of an associate that is under the Maintenance section of the Admin department must be approved by the Maintenance supervisor and the Admin Manager.

My database design:

[image: ERD]

Comment: `leave_approvals` must contain a column with `id` of the person who should approve / have approved (and, maybe, approvement date).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am also confused on what the best way to implement a multi level approval as the leave request of the lower employee(associate) must be approve by its 3 superior

Comment: This is administrative problem which is out of the DB structure. You'd analyse and create this process algorithm, after which you may implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem here.

the architecture of the database is OK for me.

> when a lower employee (associate) requests a leave that needs to be
> approved by their superiors

This is a layer of abstraction that has nothing to do with the database architecture. You will put that rule in the code.